# Error when reading file into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code which tries to determine the dimensions of a file, but each time it executes through there is this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
```

I'm unaware why this is occurring. Can anyone help debug the issue? And explain why it is happening?

```
public void loadDistances(String fname) throws Exception {
    String file = fname;
    File f = new File(file);
    Scanner in = null;

    try {
        in = new Scanner(f);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Can't find file " + file);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
    int elements = 0;

    while(in.hasNext()){ 
        while(in.next() != null){
            System.out.println(elements++);
        }
        in.nextLine(); 
        rows++;
    }
    in.close();

    cols = (elements + 1) / rows;

    // for debug purposes
    System.out.println(rows);
    System.out.println(cols);
}
```

Which reads in this file

```
0 2 3.0
1 0 2.0
2 1 7.0
2 3 1.0
3 0 6.0
```

// Checking for suggested answer

```
    int tokens = 0;
    String line;
    Scanner tokenScanner;
    Scanner fileScanner;
    Scanner lineScanner;

    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
        line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        lineScanner.nextLine() = line;
        while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
            tokens++;
        }
        rows++;
    }
```

Comment: Your additional code does nothing with the lineScanner to extract text or numbers out of it. You need to call `next()` or `nextInt()` or `nextDouble()` on it to get information out of it and into your variables. Please see edit to my answer for another way using `String#split(...)`.

Comment: I'm sorry for my incompetence, but I don't see where/what you are talking. As I trial-and-error around this, more errors arrive. (Also, do I have to assign the fileScanner to the "in" file I tried at the beginning of the method?)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Additionally, if it's not too bothersome, could you EXPLAIN how to set the scanner lineScanner to the line of text in the file so the iteration for getting the elements can be performed...

Answer (score 4):

You assign no data to your variables at all in your scanning loop, and not only that, but you read from the Scanner *twice* while checking it for data only *once*, a dangerous thing to do.

```
while(in.hasNext()){                 // **** checking once ****
    while(in.next() != null){        // **** read in and waste a token here!
        System.out.println(elements++);
    }
    in.nextLine();   // **** read in and waste a line here
    rows++;
}
in.close();
```

I would:

- Use two Scanner variables, one, fileScanner, to read in each line of text in the file,...
- And one called lineScanner to read in each token on the line.
- I'd use an outer while loop, that checks `fileScanner.hasNextLine()`, and then calls `nextLine()` to read the line into a String, say called `line`.
- I'd then create a new Scanner with the line of String created, and assign it into a lineScanner variable.
- I'd use an inner while loop that loops while `lineScanner.hasNext()`, and reads in the data into your your variables.
- I'd close the inner lineScanner at the end of the outer while loop so as not to waste resources.

---

Alternatively, you could use `String#split(...)` to split the tokens in the line read in, and then parse the Strings into numbers.  For example,

```
public List<RowData> loadDistances(String fname)
     throws FileNotFoundException, NumberFormatException {
  File file = new File(fname);
  Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
  List<RowData> rowList = new ArrayList<RowData>();

  while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
     String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
     if (tokens.length != 3) {
        // throw some custom exception
     }

     int rowNumber = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim());
     int xData = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].trim());
     double yData = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2].trim());
     rowList.add(new RowData(rowNumber, xData, yData));
  }

  if (fileScanner != null) {
     fileScanner.close();
  }

  return rowList;
}
```

---

**Edit**
By using a line Scanner, I recommend creating a second Scanner, passing in the line obtained  from the first Scanner, and extracting data from this second Scanner. You could use a while loop if you didn't know how many tokens to expect, but your data appears to be well defined, with each line holding an int, int, and double, and we can use this information to help us extract the proper data. You could use code something like this:

```
 // use previous same code as above except in the while loop:
 while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = fileScanner.nextLine(); // get line
     Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);  // create Scanner with it
     int rowNumber = 0;
     int xData = 0;
     double yData = 0.0;

     if (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        rowNumber = lineScanner.nextInt();
     } else {
        // throw a custom exception since int not found
     }
     if (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        xData = lineScanner.nextInt();
     } else {
        // throw a custom exception since int not found
     }
     if (lineScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        yData = lineScanner.nextDouble();
     } else {
        // throw a custom exception since double not found
     }

     rowList.add(new RowData(rowNumber, xData, yData));

     if (lineScanner != null) {
        lineScanner.close();
     }
  }
```

Comment: But you can't assign a Scanner to a String, correct? So how does that work?

Comment: @user2958542: correct, you assign the `next()` or `nextLine()` returned from a Scanner object to your String variable.

Comment: Thank you! I have created a sample code from your first example for assistance (I will take that due a requirement of only using Scanner).

Comment: Can you please look at the comment on the main question, and give some advice? :)